# Not able to add to cart product for Magento 2 website using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, magento2

I am doing performance testing using JMeter for Magento website. In this script I am covering end to end flow like user logged in and then add one product in cart then checkout place order. Now after successful login request , add to cart request is not executing successfully. It is not giving error but product is not showing in cart after this request.
Also there is one dynamic variable name form_key. This value is showing form_key=deleted after successfully login request.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F97Hw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9OwM.png)

Product should be visible in cart.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to add an item to the cart using the real browser and not able to do this with JMeter it means that you're sending the wrong request most probably due to missing or incorrectly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters.

So inspect request and response details using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and figure out where do the dynamic parameters come from. It might be easier to record your flow twice and compare resulting [JMeter test plans](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan). All request parameters which differ are a subject to correlation.

Also make sure to add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter) to your test plan

The online demo version of magento at https://demo-magento-2.auroracreation.com/ doesn't have any issues with the `form_key` and it's possible to add an item to the cart using JMeter script.